# Dynamic content from JSON only posts/repeats last key's data (should print all values)

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I have a UITableView (and UITableVIewCell) that I'm populating via JSON/MYSQL database. There are 10 sets of data (each containing 3 pieces of data) being called in my PHP. My UITableView is set up to post 3 of the sets. 3 sets of data are printed in my table, however, they are all the same piece of data. How can I make it print the most recent 3 sets?

**MainTableController.m**

```
@implementation MainTableViewController
@synthesize textNeedTitle, textNeedPoster ,textNeedDescrip;

-(IBAction)unwindToRootVC:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    // Nothing needed here.
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 3;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TestTableViewCell *cell = (TestTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://domain.com/json2.php"];
    NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];


    if(!error)
    {
        for (NSDictionary * needs in jsonArray)
        {
            cell.textNeedTitle.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needTitle"];
            cell.textNeedPoster.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needPoster"];
            cell.textNeedDescrip.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needDescrip"];
        }
    }

    else
    {
        textNeedTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error--%@",[error description]];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

My PHP is setup to call the most recent 10 posts, but is there an added necessary code I'm missing in my Objective C?

Comment: you are making a synchronous request in `cellForRow` method. Blocking your UI. that's pretty bad

Comment: @Kabira well...thank you for letting me know. How might I make it...better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making your webservice call in `cellForRow` which is called once per cell is made to be shown.

Now currently what is happening is cell 1 shown -> you download data -> traverse it -> and show the last element vale in the `cell.textNeedTitle` That is this code

```
for (NSDictionary * needs in jsonArray)
        {
            cell.textNeedTitle.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needTitle"];
            cell.textNeedPoster.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needPoster"];
            cell.textNeedDescrip.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needDescrip"];
        }
```

What you want is first download your data in `viewDidLoad` which is when your view is fully initialized. Read up on the docs more.

So changing your code to like this.

`in .h file`

```
interface MyClassVC:UIViewController {
   NSArray *myDataArray;
}
```

`in .m file`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];   


    // get the data from the URL , you are only getting it synchronous currently. change to asynchronous . read the docs
    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://domain.com/json2.php"];
    NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
    NSError *error;
    myDataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    [tableView reloadData]; // if tableView is unidentified make the tableView IBOutlet
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return myDataArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TestTableViewCell *cell = (TestTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *needs = myDataArray[indexPath.row]; // get the data dict for the row
    cell.textNeedTitle.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needTitle"];
    cell.textNeedPoster.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needPoster"];
    cell.textNeedDescrip.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needDescrip"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: When applying these changes, I get an error that causes the build to fail. TestTableViewCell *cell = (TestTableViewCell *) [[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath]; throws the error "Local declaration of 'tableView' hides instance variable". Any ideas? Thank you for your thorough answer btw!

Comment: you can ignore that error. although that error explains itself tableView iVar is also there and in the method a local variable with `tableView` is also being declared. To solve it you can make a different name IBOutlet. but you can still continue currently. no problem with the warning

Comment: Also, found a stray ] and now the build succeeds but quickly crashes. The debug area tells me "reason: 'data parameter is nil'" Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: can you tell which line ?

Comment: Well...that was actually my fault. Forgot to readjust the domain. Thank you so much! This worked like a charm! Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition of Kabira's answer, it could use async loading to avoid UI freezing.

Added error report as suggested in your original question.

```
interface MyClassVC:UIViewController {
   NSArray *myDataArray;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://domain.com/json2.php"];
            NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSError *error;
                jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
                if(error) {
                    textNeedTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error--%@",[error description]];
                } else {
                    [tableView reloadData]; // if tableView is unidentified make the tableView IBOutlet
                }
            });
        });
    });

}
```